# UITableViewCell autosizing masks not applied on some cells after orientation change

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, orientation, autosize

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` which called `ProductiPadCell`, which loads from a custom xib.

It works perfect until I make an orientation change on my iPad. Than some of the cell's don't get autosized, actually they autosize to opposite orientations. (portrait autosized on landscape and vice versa)

I don't manually update my `tableView` nor my `UITableViewCell`'s `setNeedsLayout` method.

This is how my cell looks after `UIInterfaceOrientation` change;

[image]

The cell on the bottom doesn't get updated.

I would like to figure out how this bug is happening and how to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: no, I am targeting iOS 5 as well. Auto layout is disabled.